# Создание пользовательских функций на C++ для записи в файл структуру

Tags: c++

Доброе время суток. При планировании курсовой работы, я начал определять какие будут функции содержаться в моем ПО. Я имею два похожих объекта(Доктор,Пациент),
Поля у этих объектов примерно одинаковые, и вот сижу думаю реализовать общую функцию по записи структуры в файл, но если все реализовать все в одной функции то как мне кажется  функция будет очень большая или все таки лучше сделать две функции , одна записывает структуру пациентов, а вторая записывает доктора.
как лучше сделать?  какие советы можете дать?

Comment: Ну если у вас там объекты - сделайте для объектов метод WriteToFile

Comment: моё личное мнение что либо использовать универсальный механизм сериализации (найти хорошую библиотеку или просто бинарно всю структуру) или каждая структура имеет свой метод для записи себя в файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вряд ли `Доктор` и `Пациент` будут наследниками какого-то общего класса (таковым может быть разве что `Человек`). Но если у них действительно много общего, то, возможно, имеет смысл выделить общего предка с виртуальной функцией-членом для записи; соответственно. у классов-потомков виртуальные функции будут дописывать специфичную информацию. Делать одну функцию не-член для записи двух разных структур (по всей видимости, с `if-else` или `switch`), на мой взгляд, решение не оптимальное.

Проблема только в правильном чтении из файла - здесь должен быть диспетчер, который при чтении должен корректно вызвать функцию соответствующего класса (это уже второй вопрос, впрочем).

Для курсового проекта, я думаю, прибегать к внешним библиотекам особого смысла нет. На написание такого простого своего вы потратите времени не больше, чем на изучение чужого, зато получите бесценные шишки на голове :), именуемые опытом...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ, зачастую, зависит от выбранного подхода.

В самом простом случае можно выделить базовый класс с виртуальными функциями `serialize` и `deserialize`, позволяющими произвести, соответственно, сохранение и загрузку элемента с использованием выбранного формата (байтовое представление, json, xml, и т.д.). Я бы не стал нагружать этот класс функцией записи в файл, потому что этим должен заниматься отдельный класс.

Спустя некоторое время, вы столкнетесь с ситуацией, в которой придется внести изменения в ваши структуры. Кроме того, придется дополнительно поддерживать ранее сериализованные данные в файлы.

Можно, конечно, в качестве учебного задания реализовать различные механизмы версинирования, но гораздо проще будет воспользоваться готовой реализацией библиотеки для сериализации данных, к примеру - [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning)